# London bus stops registry

Tags: data-request, transportation, uk, public-transport

I'm trying to find public dataset where it's possible to find NaPTAN code from bus stop number displayed on the plate on each stop.

For example for "CROFTON PARK STATION" number on plate is **58556** and maching NaPTAN code is **490018484N**  (source: https://tfl.gov.uk/bus/stop/490018484N/crofton-park-station)

From [public enquiry](https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/unique_bus_stop_identifier?unfold=1) I found out that NaPTAN codes relate to BODS codes. Unfortunately, I was only able to find an outdated lookup spreadsheet that doesn't have the newer NaPTAN codes. [data.gov.uk's NaPTAN database](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/naptan) covers public transportation but lacks local bus stop numbers.

Is there way to translate BODS code to NaPTAN or might be someone knows where it's possible to download that database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it at http://naptan.app.dft.gov.uk/datarequest/help under GTFS section, direct link: http://naptan.app.dft.gov.uk/datarequest/GTFS.ashx